# deleted automatically telegram bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I created a telegram robot that forwards video files by selecting Start. And I want them to be deleted automatically after 1 hour. Can anyone help me?

```
context.bot.sendDocument(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, document='https://t.me/mychanel/2',caption="1")
context.bot.sendDocument(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, document='https://t.me/mychanel/3',caption="2")
context.bot.sendDocument(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, document='https://t.me/mycha
```

nel/4',caption="3")

how can I delete auto those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do
`message =context.bot.sendDocument(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, document='https://t.me/mychanel/2',caption="1")`

And save the `message.message_id` with a timestamp in a data structure, list or dict, after that you can schedule a periodic thread that do
`bot.delte_message(message_id,chat_id)` on the expired videos